# Pyglet Player.seek() function not working?

Tags: python, python-3.x, media, pyglet

I am trying to build a simple media tool in Pyglet, which requires a seek feature. Files are loaded, paused, and then told to seek to a specific time; however, the file does not seek when Player.seek() is called. Below is the test code I am using:

```
import os
import pyglet
from os.path import abspath, isfile

def loadsong(filename):
   # check for file
   print("Attempting to load "+filename)
   filename = abspath(filename)
   if not ( isfile(filename) ):
      raise Exception(filename+" not found.")
   # create a player for this file
   song = pyglet.media.load(filename)
   source = song.play()
   source.eos_action = source.EOS_LOOP
   source.pause()
   return source

music = loadsong("test.mp3")
music.seek(57)
music.play()
pyglet.app.run()
```

What am I doing wrong here? I am using Python 3.5.2, Pyglet 1.2 alpha 1, and AVBin 11 alpha 4.

Comment: If anyone is having an issue where the file continues to have its timer increased but is muted when seeking, try doing player.play() immediately after seeking if it's not already paused

Answer (score 1):

First of all, the error you're getting is quite important.
But I'll assume it's a `Segmentation fault (core dumped)` on the row:

```
music.seek(12)
```

Another quick note, fix your indentation! You're using 3 spaces and whether you are a space guy or a tab guy - 3 spaces is just odd -

The reason for you getting a segmentation fault when trying to seek is most likely because of AVbin, it's an old (and dead afaik) project.

I hacked together something more similar to a music player and here's an example on how you can use `Seek` with wav files:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.gl import *
from os.path import abspath, isfile

pyglet.options['audio'] = ('pulseaudio', 'alsa', 'openal', 'silent')
pyglet.have_avbin=False
key = pyglet.window.key

def loadsong(filename):
    # check for file
    filename = abspath(filename)

    # create a player for this file
    player = pyglet.media.Player()
    player.queue(pyglet.media.load(filename, streaming=False))
    #player.play()
    #song.eos_action = song.EOS_LOOP
    #song.pause()
    return player

class main(pyglet.window.Window):
    def __init__ (self):
        super(main, self).__init__(300, 300, fullscreen = False)
        self.alive = 1

        self.player = loadsong('./test.wav')

    def on_draw(self):
        self.render()

    def on_close(self):
        self.alive = 0

    def on_key_press(self, symbol, modifiers):
        if symbol == key.ESCAPE: # [ESC]
            self.alive = 0
        elif symbol == key.SPACE:
            if self.player.playing:
                self.player.pause()
            else:
                self.player.play()
        elif symbol == key.RIGHT:
            print('Skipping to:',self.player.time+2)
            self.player.source.seek(self.player.time+2)
        elif symbol == key.LEFT:
            print('Rewinding to:',self.player.time-2)
            self.player.source.seek(self.player.time-2)

    def render(self):
        self.clear()

        #source = pyglet.text.Label(str(self.player.source.info.title.decode('UTF-8')), x=20, y=300-30)
        volume = pyglet.text.Label(str(self.player.volume*100)+'% volume', x=20, y=40)
        p_time = pyglet.text.Label(str(self.player.time), x=20, y=20)

        #source.draw()
        volume.draw()
        p_time.draw()

        self.flip()

    def run(self):
        while self.alive == 1:
            self.render()

            # -----------> This is key <----------
            # This is what replaces pyglet.app.run()
            # but is required for the GUI to not freeze
            #
            event = self.dispatch_events()

x = main()
x.run()
```

A few important notes:

```
pyglet.have_avbin=False
```

This will turn off AVbin completely, there is probably a way to turn it off for individual sources.. But since I rarely play around with it I honestly have no idea of how to.. So off it goes :)

Secondly:

```
streaming=False
```

On the `media.load()` call is quite important, otherwise you might get weird artifacts in your sound and or no sound at all. I got instance to a super high pitched scratching noise that almost made me deaf without that flag.

Other than that, the code is quite straight forward.

```
self.player.source.seek(<time>)
```

Is called on the player object that is a instance of `pyglet.media.Player()`. And it works brilliantly.

Another work-around would be to manually install [AVbin 7](https://code.google.com/archive/p/avbin/) which **appears** to be working better, but I'm reluctant to install it on this machine just for testing purposes.. But the overall info i've gathered over the years is that that old library works better with Mp3 files.

Comment: It's not actually giving me any error at all, and certainly not a segfault. The file plays fine, it just refuses to actually seek. Is there a way to use your workaround which remains compatible with .mp3 files? Re-encoding all music to .wav is not feasible.

Comment: @A.Vist The file plays fine here too, until I try to seek it. Then all of a sudden I get a segfault (On Linux). Can't really tell why that's happening but if the above code didn't fix it and you can't use .wav, my best guess is to file a bug report over at their bitbucket page.

Answer (score 1):

Please ensure Player.playing is True before invoking Player.seek().
In the end of loadsong() function, you invoked the pause() that will set the Player.playing to False.

you could try:

```
music.play()
music.seek(57)
```

instead of:

```
music.seek(57)
music.play()
```

Answer (score 1):

The following example uses pyglet 1.5.6, the seek() function works on my macbook pro, but negative on my windows 10:

```
import pyglet
from pyglet.window import key

source = pyglet.media.load(VIDEO_FILE_PATH)
fmt = source.video_format

player = pyglet.media.Player()
player.queue(source)
player.play()

window = pyglet.window.Window(width=fmt.width, height=fmt.height)

@window.event
def on_draw():
    player.get_texture().blit(0, 0)

@window.event
def on_key_press(symbol, modifiers):
    if symbol == key.LEFT:
        player.seek(player.time - 3.5)   
    elif symbol == key.RIGHT:
        player.seek(player.time + 3.5)   
    elif symbol == key.SPACE:
        if player.playing:
            player.pause()
        else:
            player.play()
        
pyglet.app.run()
```